# My css is not being applied in github how to fix?

Tags: html, css

When I add my css file to the the github repository the html is being applied but not the css

repository: https://github.com/Hamza200903/Hamza-s-Way-To-Success/settings/pages

Comment: Use $ git add . if not used, it adds all the modified files.

Answer (score -2):

on my computer is working properly
https://github.com/Hamza200903/Hamza-s-Way-To-Success/